# Seq.contains in SQL in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data structure:

- `id: int`
- `records: Seq[String]`
- `other: boolean`

In a json file, in order to ease testing:

```
var data = sc.makeRDD(Seq[String](
   "{\"id\":1, \"records\": [\"one\", \"two\", \"three\"], \"other\": true}", 
   "{\"id\": 2, \"records\": [\"two\"], \"other\": true}", 
   "{\"id\": 3, \"records\": [\"one\"], \"other\": false }"))
sqlContext.jsonRDD(data).registerTempTable("temp")
```

And I'd like to filter down to just records with `one` in the `records` field and `other` equal to `true` using just SQL.

I can do it via a `filter` (see below), but can it be done just using SQL?

```
sqlContext
    .sql("select id, records from temp where other = true")
    .rdd.filter(t => t.getAs[Seq[String]]("records").contains("one"))
    .collect()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark SQL supports the vast majority of Hive features, thus you can use `array_contains` to do the job :

```
spark.sql("select id, records from temp where other = true and array_contains(records,'one')").show
# +---+-----------------+
# | id|          records|
# +---+-----------------+
# |  1|[one, two, three]|
# +---+-----------------+
```

**Note:** In **spark 1.5**, `sqlContext.jsonRDD` is *deprecated* , use the following instead :

```
sqlContext.read.format("json").json(data).registerTempTable("temp")
```